# Get segue.destination as view controller in switch case statement

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to write the following switch statement in such a way that the 'let dentViewController' part is happening on the 'switch segue.destination' or on the 'case is DamageTypeDentViewController:' line?

(I feel I am doing double work with the 'case is' and 'let dentViewController = segue.destination as')

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination {
    case is DamageTypeDentViewController:
        let dentViewController = segue.destination as? DamageTypeDentViewController
        dentViewController.doSomething()

    default:
        return
    }

}
```

Comment: you can write `(segue.destination as? DamageTypeDentViewController)?.doSomething()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination {
    case let dentViewController as DamageTypeDentViewController:
        dentViewController.doSomething()

    default:
        return
    }
}
```

---

And if there is only one case to check you could write

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if case let dentViewController as DamageTypeDentViewController = segue.destination {
        dentViewController.doSomething()
    }
}
```

or even simpler

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let dentViewController = segue.destination as? DamageTypeDentViewController {
        dentViewController.doSomething()
    }
}
```